# SSRS Email subscribtion fails after added expression

Tags: email, reporting-services, expression, subscription

I have an SSRS reporting service which sends reports as email subscription. Everything was working fine. 
Now I added a expression to one of the column. After that I was able to view the reports in the URL, but the timely subscribed emails are not flowing out. The status is pending for so long and finally it fails saying "Thread aborted"

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the error "System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted." occurs when we call Thread.Abort() explicit, or there is unhandled exception occurred.

In this case, it should be unhandled exception, as SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) catches almost all exceptions. Maybe you could  enable verbose log for SSRS to trace more detailed error log, this may help us to troubleshooting the issue. If there is dump file generated. The dump files will be generated in the same folder of the log files.

Dont have the rep to post this a comment.